# Prior of a product

Tags: bayesian, prior

Let say, we have N servers. Every server is in production for a different amount of years. For every server, we know how many times this server crashed, the total for all the years. A number of crashes can be modelled by Poisson distribution.
$X_i \sim  Poisson(\lambda_i) $ let's define $\lambda_i = \theta_it_i$ where $\theta_i$ is number of failures per year and $t_i$ is number of years.

I can assume that prior for $\theta_i$ is the same for all servers. They all are similar pieces of equipment. Can I make the same assumption for $\lambda_i$? This multiplication makes me wonder. Should I consider $t_i$ as a random variable too? Multiplication of a random variable on a constant shouldn't change our assumption on a prior, but multiplication of two random variables could change it.

I'm trying to build a model looking on example but wonder if my setup is the same as one in the example.

Comment: What are observed? $X_i$ the total number of crashes and $t_i$ the number of years the server was in production? What else?

Comment: That's all I have. Number of crashes and number of years for every server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple model is:

$$X_i\sim\text{Poisson}\big(\exp(\alpha + \theta t_i)\big)$$

where $X_i$ and $t_i$ are treated as observed variables (or data), and $\alpha$ and $\theta$ are unobserved variables (or parameters to be estimated).

This model assumes:

- that all the servers functioned similarly, and
- the number of crashes grew exponentially with years of production.

$e^\alpha$ is the expected number of crashes when the server is 0 years. And $e^\theta$ will give you % change in crashes for each additional year of production.

And you only need to place priors on the constants, $\alpha$ and $\theta$.

---

A different model is:

$$X_i\sim\text{Poisson}\big(\exp(\alpha_i + \ln{(t_i)}\big)$$

This model assumes:

- the longer a server runs, the more it fails in a constant way, and
- the failure rates differs across servers as captured by $\alpha_i$.

This is likely a stronger model given your comments. And $e^{(\alpha_i)}$ will return the expected failure rate (failures/year) for each server $i$.

There is only need to place a prior on $\alpha_i$, $\alpha_i$ would be what is known as an observation-level random effect. And is similar in spirit to a negative-binomial model.

---

For fully observed variables such as $t_i$, there is no need to place a prior on them, since they are not outcomes.

Comment: Thank you for this model, it looks very nice. Looking on data, I would say that number of crashes doesn't follow exponential law though. Some servers are very old but produced very few failures. Some servers not that old but give much more trouble. The point of my question is multiplication by $t_i$ is actually can change the prior distribution. I have to choose prior for it, and I think if it can be the same prior as for $\theta_i$

Comment: @Alsin I updated my response by recommending an additional model to accommodate your comment. There is no need to place a prior on $t_i$ since it is fully observed, and you are not modeling $t_i$.

Comment: Wow, thank you for extending your model. It is precious to see how you do it. Your comment about $t_i$, probably, explains my question. I still have to digest it. I have a feeling that your model is better than what I have as an example.